# About importance of electric flux

Tags: electrostatics, electric-fields, gauss-law

Why is electric flux defined at all? It seems that without having symmetry in objects, we cannot use it to find something important. Please shed some light on its history also.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Electric Flux - What is the point?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/165936/)

Comment: For questions about the history of science, the right venue is [hsm.se]; see https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/8930/ for more details.

Comment: If the answers in the linked thread don't answer your query, then please edit this post to explain why.